# Java framework to generate unit tests automatically

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

Is there any Java framework to generate **Unit tests** automatically just by feeding Java source code to the framework?

If no, why isn't it possible?

Comment: How would it be possible? What determines valid test cases?

Comment: You can generate tests automatically, but consider what they are actually testing: if the tests were generated from your current implementation, all they can test is that your new implementation does the same thing; it can't detect existing incorrect behaviour, because there is nothing to say what is incorrect. You have to write the tests yourself to find these. (You can find some bugs using fuzz testing, however)

Answer (score 4):

Even if is was possible, it is a **bad idea** to auto-generate your tests:

Unit tests are written to ensure a certain **quality of the code**. A generator will not be able to understand the exact logic of what you write, this is why you must do it yourself.

If this task is too long and difficult, you can start with at least by testing the most important classes of your code. It will probably enable you to ensure **good coverage** and possibly detect some bugs.